# VBA to Java Convert for Doubleklick in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to convert a Makro in Excel/VB into Google Spreadsheets

I Tried to use Java Converters but it won't work the way I do:

```
private final void Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Range Target, boolean Cancel) {
    if (!(Intersect(Target, Range("A50:R131")) == null)) {
        this.Unprotect;
        if ((Target == "")) {
            Target = "X";
        }
        else {
            Target = "";
        }

        this.Protect;
        Cancel = true;
    }

}
```

This is the VB Code i Use succesfully in Excel:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A50:R131")) Is Nothing Then

    Me.Unprotect

    If Target = "" Then
        Target = "X"
        Else
        Target = ""
    End If
    Me.Protect

    Cancel = True
End If
```

End Sub

In between i Tryed in Javascript Thx to [snapstromegon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7480508/snapstromegon)

but I Got an Error in Line 6: Syntaxfailure?

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var nl = getNewLine()

function getNewLine() {
    var agent = navigator.userAgent

    if (agent.indexOf("Win") >= 0) <--- What is wrong here?
        return "\r\n"
    else
        if (agent.indexOf("Mac") >= 0)
            return "\r"

    return "\r"

}

pagecode = 'Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A50:R131")) Is Nothing Then

        Me.Unprotect

        If Target = "" Then
            Target = "X"
            Else
            Target = ""
        End If
        Me.Protect

        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub'

document.write(pagecode);

</script>
```

Comment: You need to convert it to Javascript, not Java. Those languages are just as related as C and Python.

Comment: @Snapstromegon I tried but also Error Code is Below :)

Comment: You can't do multiline strings in JavaScript like that, FYI

Comment: Can you maybe help to corret this? Im not a Pro in JS :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Can you maybe help to corret this?

Comment: @KroXlBullySam just put `\n\ ` (without the space I had to put for formatting purposes) at the end of each line in that string

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time trying to convert a VBA/Excel Macro to Google Sheets. Instead start from scratch.

I don't think that there is a JavaScript converter that delivers the result you are looking for because Google Sheets use Google Apps Script which provides special services that are not included on JavaScript.

To start from scratch, first you should understand the differences between Excel and Google Sheets as several features like the macro recorder and sheet/range protection while are similar, they doesn't work in the same way so maybe you should change the design of your solution.

References

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides7sheets)